# How do I specify an optional dependency in a CMake package configuration file?

Tags: cmake, dependencies, cmake-modules

I'm trying to specify correctly the dependencies in the `MyLibConfig.cmake` file of my project.
In `CMakeLists.txt` I have something like this:

```
find_package(aLib REQUIRED)
find_package(bLib)
```

So in `MyLibConfig.cmake` I wrote something like:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(aLib REQUIRED)
find_dependency(bLib)
```

Now, when I write another project that needs myLib, I do:

```
find_package(MyLib REQUIRED)
```

This fails because the MyLib configuration file doesn't find bLib, but I would like it to be treated as optional. What is the best Modern CMake practice to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_dependency` is used only for (initially) REQUIRED packages.

`find_package` for non-REQUIRED sub-package remains the same when "copied" into `XXXConfig.cmake` script.

For `CMakeLists.txt` contained

```
find_package(aLib REQUIRED)
find_package(bLib)
```

corresponded content of `MyLibConfig.cmake` would be:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
# for REQUIRED package 'find_package' is replaced with 'find_dependency',
# but 'REQUIRED' keyword is omited.
find_dependency(aLib)
# for non-REQUIRED package 'find_package' remains.
find_package(bLib)
```

---

It is important that `REQUIRED` keyword is **NOT** passed to the `find_dependency` macro.
So, would one call

```
find_package(MyLib) # Without 'REQUIRED'!
```

and `aLib` package would be missed, then with (failed) call

```
find_dependency(aLib)
```

CMake would treat `MyLib` to be missed too (and would print an appropriate message), but won't stop the configuration because of that.

Comment: Thanks. Since I would like to forward at least the QUIET option, do you think a solution like the following is acceptable?
`set(USE_B @USE_B@) # <-- I set this if B_FOUND`
`if (USE_B) find_dependency(bLib) endif()`

Comment: Yes, if `bLib` is required only for some configuration of your package, then using conditional `find_dependency` is perfectly OK.